# How to format string in Clojure by using map-indexed and vector

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I am trying to read content from a file which is in the format :

ID|Name|Country-Name|Phone-Number eg:

```
1|Austin|Germany|34-554567
2|Mary Jane|Australia|45-78647
```

I am using following code to fetch data from it :

```
(
  map-indexed
    #(vector %1 %2)
    (
      map #(vec(.split #"\|" %1))
      (
        line-seq (clojure.java.io/reader "test.txt")
      )
    )
)
```

with this code I am getting this output:

```
([0 ["1" "Austin" "Germany" "34-554567"]] [1 ["2" "Mary Jane" "Australia" "45-78647"]] [2 ["3" "King Kong" "New-Zealand" "35-467533"]])
```

I want the output to be like:

```
ID:["name" "country-name" "phone-number"]
ID:["name" "country-name" "phone-number"]
```

eg:

```
1:["Austin" "Germany" "34-554567"]
2:["Mary Jane" "Australia" "45-78647"]
```

where ID is to be incremented by 1 (start from 1,2,3 and so on) and each result lists the identity or ID, succeeded by the data united with the ID and it should be sorted by an ID.

What changes do I do to my code to make this happen?

Comment: Do you mean to build a map keyed by ID? Try `(into {} your-output )`

Comment: looks like what you are asking is very close to what you are getting.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to assign the id number that is in my text file to what I am getting as an output. So that at the end I'll sort them easily

Comment: @manandearth actually what I am getting now dosen't fit to my actual output. Moreover I find little difficult to assign everything as a vector and fetch every values with their indexes

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
(into {}  (map-indexed
       #(vector (inc %1) (rest %2))
       (repeat 2 ["1" "Austin" "Germany" "34-554567"])))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data already has indexes in it:

```
(def data
  "1|Austin|Germany|34-554567
   2|Mary Jane|Australia|45-78647
   3|King Kong|New-Zealand|35-467533 ")

(defn fmt [line]
  (let [sections (-> line
                     str/trim
                     (str/split #"\|")) ]
    sections) )

(defn run []
  (let [lines (vec (str/split-lines data)) ]
    (mapv fmt lines)))

(run)
```

with result:

```
sections => ["1" "Austin" "Germany" "34-554567"]
sections => ["2" "Mary Jane" "Australia" "45-78647"]
sections => ["3" "King Kong" "New-Zealand" "35-467533"]
```

If you wanted to throw away the indexes in the data, you could generate your own like so:

```
(defn fmt [idx line]
  (let [sections      (-> line
                          str/trim
                          (str/split #"\|"))
        sections-keep (rest sections)
        result        (apply vector idx sections-keep)]
    result))

(defn run []
  (let [lines (vec (str/split-lines data))]
    (mapv fmt (range 1 1e9) lines)))
```

---

## Update

If you want to use a disk file, do this:

```
(def data
  "1|Austin|Germany|34-554567
   2|Mary Jane|Australia|45-78647
   3|King Kong|New-Zealand|35-467533 ")

(defn fmt [idx line]
  (let [sections      (-> line
                          str/trim
                          (str/split #"\|"))
        sections-keep (rest sections)
        result        (apply vector idx sections-keep)]
    result))

(defn run [filename]
  (let [lines (vec (str/split-lines (slurp filename)))]
    (mapv fmt (range 1 1e9) lines)))

(let [filename "/tmp/demo.txt"]
  (spit filename data)
  (run filename))
```

Comment: in your updated answer this is what I understand. You are trying to put data in a file named _demo.txt_ and then reading that file using slurp. In fmt function, you have applied trim and split operations and then in run defn your are mapping vector by passing fmt as an argument. Please correct me if I am wrong. By the way, I already have a file from where I am reading data. Is there any need to create a new one as shown _demo.txt_. Things bouncing over my head.

Comment: I only added the `spit` to show the creation of the file. If you have one already you obviously don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

A guess:

```
(def data
  "1|Austin|Germany|34-554567
   2|Mary Jane|Australia|45-78647
   3|King Kong|New-Zealand|35-467533")

(->> (for [line (clojure.string/split data #"[ ]*[\r\n]+[ ]*")]
       (-> line (clojure.string/split #"\|") rest vec))
     (map vector (rest (range))))

; ([1 ["Austin" "Germany" "34-554567"]]
;  [2 ["Mary Jane" "Australia" "45-78647"]]
;  [3 ["King Kong" "New-Zealand" "35-467533"]])
```

Although I'm not sure why you want to have explicit auto-generated ID in the result and ignore the serial-number you've got in the original data.

Optionally add `(into (sorted-map))` to the end so you get the sequential ids mapped to values, and this retains the id order unlike a hash-map.

Comment: Hello @NikoNyrh, can you please update your answer with mine as I am facing a little problem while fetching data from text file and applying your mentioned operation on it.

Comment: You can use `slurp` to get file contents as a string, at least if you use the absolute file path. The "output" you describe is not a Clojure data structure, so it cannot be produced by a Clojure function. Do you want it to be printed out instead? Maybe you'd want to insert it `into` a `sorted-map`?

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I fetch a value of (([1 ["Austin" "Germany" "34-554567"]]) something like a[1] give result 1, a[2] give result "Austin" etc.

Comment: There are a few functions for getting  an element from a vector, such as `nth` and `get`. They can also operate as "functions", for example `(["Austin" "Germany" "34-554567"] 1)` evaluates to `"Germany"`.